# Why tracking URL is not working in Tridion Outbound Email module?

Tags: web8, outbound-email, audience-manager, tracking

I have used DWT Templating for the content to be rendered in the Outbound Email. Used `GetLinkTrackingURL` method as shown below to get the URL which can be tracked.

```
@@GetLinkTrackingURL('${link.link.internal_link}','${link.link_text}')@@
```

We configured the tracking url to /outboundemail/Tracking. In our web application, we are routing that url to an action with the following code:

```
    public void Tracking()
    {
        Handler handler = new Handler(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request);
        Response.Redirect(handler.Url);
    }
```

This works in all of our environments, except one. In this environment, the link present in the email received, is not redirecting to the actual URL. List of TBBs used in the Page Template are listed below:

- Outbound E-mail Pre-processing
- Outbound Email Page DW Layout
- Outbound E-mail Post-processing (with parameter `TrackLinks` as `Yes`)

Does anyone come across this issue? What might be going wrong here?

Comment: Is that a different CM or CD environment? If your setup already works, I'd suspect it's something environment-specific rather than something to do with the TBBs. What do the logs show?

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is. Does handler.Url return null or an empty string? Or is the problem earlier? Does your code get hit? Have you tried debugging it to see what the values are?